# iOS app won't start after app upgrade

Tags: ios, crash, upgrade, startup

One user has a problem with one of my apps after the latest upgrade. She says the app will not open. It sounds like she sees the Default launch screen for a second and then it disappears i.e. it crashes when trying to run app code.
Also, she says when she double taps the Home button to see the apps currently running, she sees my app, with the "normal" type of screen i.e. a table with a few entries (which was created with the version prior to the upgrade).
She has tried powering off and on.
Can anyone offer any suggestions on what might be happening. No other user has reported the same problem.
It may be that she could remove the app and reinstall, but then she would lose all of her data which would be bad. Is there any way of reinstalling without removing from the iPhone?

EDIT: I just got a little more information from the user. As I said before, after the crash, when she presses the Home button twice to see running apps, she sees my app, with a few entries in the opening screen table. What is interesting, for the upgrade, I changed the order of the entries. I also added a tool bar with 2 buttons. She sent me a screen shot and what she is getting is the screen you would expect when running the old version i.e. the table ordered in the old way, and no toolbar. I don't know if this just means my app started to run and crashed before reordering the table and adding the toolbar, or if the installation got corrupted so she is not really running the new application properly. Does that sound feasible? Would there be any way to reinstall the app without removing it (and its data) first?

Comment: I'd think it more likely that you could restore the data from a backup, although it sounds like there isn't much data involved, so re-entering that data might be acceptable (if it is even possible to do that w/ this app).  Note that it might be this data that is *causing* the crash...

Comment: Do you mean a backup specific to my app, or a device backup? The upgrade allows users to backup their data - unfortunately the previous version did not. Re-entering the data will be a bigger task than it would appear from what I said above - the opening screen is a table of just a few entries, but tapping a row then displays more detailed tables etc. I am worried that something in the data could be causing a crash, though I have never seen this from any other user. Do you know if a crash report would shed any light on this - I have never had to analyse a crash report before.

Comment: Do you think the following is possible? I should be able to find in Organiser an archived version of the previous release. I could try to then create an adhoc version of that release for the user to install. Hopefully if this can be done, it would run without the data being lost?? Then she could try to do the upgrade again and see if the same problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using CoreData? If you are, and you made changes to the manage model without properly migrating, you may have caused your app to crash.

Look here for more information:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html

Comment: I am using Core Data but did not change the model. As far as I know, the problem has only happened to one user. I do know that other users are completely fine with the upgrade.